# How to validate geographic locations (like on careers.stackoverflow.com)?

Tags: geolocation

On http://careers.stackoverflow.com, the edit page under

- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit

– section **Where do you want to work?** – has the neat property, that it validates geographic locations and gives them some canonical name. E.g. I enter

```
Subotica
```

and it will complete to

```
Zubotica, Severna Bachka, Serbia
```

Does it use any public API? Are there any open source implementations of such a geocompleter available for further studies? Are the sanitizations provided by http://www.geonames.org/?